# Sparse matrix support for long vectors (over 2^31 elements)

Tags: r, memory, sparse-matrix, xgboost

I know this question has been asked in the past ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24236426/how-to-get-a-big-sparse-matrix-in-r-231-1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31861403/r-creating-sparse-matrix-with-more-than-231-1-non-zero-elements?rq=1), for example), but those questions are years old and unresolved. I am wondering if any solutions have been created since then. The issue is that the Matrix package in R cannot handle long vectors (length greater than 2^31 - 1). In my case, a sparse matrix is necessary for running an XGBoost model because of memory and time constraints. The XGBoost `xgb.DMatrix` supports using a `dgCMatrix` object. However, due to the size of my data, trying to create a sparse matrix results in an error. Here's an example of the issue. (Warning: this uses 50-60 GB RAM.)

```
i <- rep(1, 2^31)
j <- i
j[(2^30): length(j)] <- 2
x <- i
s <- sparseMatrix(i = i, j = j, x = x)
```

> Error in validityMethod(as(object, superClass)) : long vectors not supported yet: ../../src/include/Rinlinedfuns.h:137

As of 2019, are there any solutions to this issue?

I am using the latest version of the `Matrix` package, 1.2-15.

Comment: please share your code which is resulting in this error.

Comment: @abhiieor totally forgot to add an example. Thank you, updated

Answer (score 2):

The sparse matrix algebra R package **spam** with its **spam64** extension supports sparse matrices with more than 2^31-1 non-zero elements.

A simple example (requires ~50 Gb memory and takes ~5 mins to run):

```
## -- a regular 32-bit spam matrix
library(spam) # version 2.2-2
s <- spam(1:2^30)
summary(s) 
## Matrix object of class 'spam' of dimension 1073741824x1,
##     with 1073741824 (row-wise) nonzero elements.
##     Density of the matrix is 100%.
## Class 'spam'

## -- a 64-bit spam matrix with 2^31 non-zero entries
library(spam64)
s <- cbind(s, s) 
summary(s) 
## Matrix object of class 'spam' of dimension 1073741824x2,
##     with 2147483648 (row-wise) nonzero elements.
##     Density of the matrix is 100%.
## Class 'spam'

## -- add zeros to make the dimension 2^31 x 2^31
pad(s) <- c(2^31, 2^31) 
summary(s) 
## Matrix object of class 'spam' of dimension 2147483648x2147483648,
##     with 2147483648 (row-wise) nonzero elements.
##     Density of the matrix is 4.66e-08%.
## Class 'spam'
```

Some links:

- https://cran.r-project.org/package=spam
- https://cran.r-project.org/package=spam64
- https://cran.r-project.org/package=dotCall64
- https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cageo.2016.11.015
- https://doi.org/10.1016/j.softx.2018.06.002

I am one of the authors of **dotCall64** and **spam**.

Comment: Not only it is customary to disclose that you are the author of the advertised library, normally you also should not answer the same thing to multiple questions. If the questions are really the same, a duplicate vote is in order instead. You should at least tailor the answer to answer the exact specific question you are answering

Comment: I see your point and updated the reply. BTW this question is obviously a duplication...