# Support for large sparse matrices R

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, reticulate, text2vec

Is there any support for large sparse matrices in R? I'm currently dealing with a 1.9M sparse square matrix with about `0.001` density.

I wanted to stress test the creating of this matrix in R on my AWS spot instance with 480gb memory.

```
library(Matrix)

DIMS = as.numeric(1988463)
DENSITY = as.numeric(0.001)
VALS = as.numeric(DIMS*DIMS*DENSITY)

i <- sample(DIMS, VALS, replace = TRUE)    
j <- sample(DIMS, VALS, replace = TRUE)    
x <- rpois(VALS, 10)

sp_matrix <- sparseMatrix(i = i, 
                          j = j, 
                          x = as.numeric(x), 
                          dims=list(DIMS, DIMS))
```

However, I get this error.

```
Error in validityMethod(as(object, superClass)): long vectors not supported yet: ../../src/include/Rinlinedfuns.h:522
Traceback:

1. system.time(sp_matrix <- sparseMatrix(i = i, j = j, x = as.numeric(x), 
 .     dims = list(DIMS, DIMS)))
2. sparseMatrix(i = i, j = j, x = as.numeric(x), dims = list(DIMS, 
 .     DIMS))
3. validObject(r)
4. anyStrings(validityMethod(as(object, superClass)))
5. isTRUE(x)
6. validityMethod(as(object, superClass))
Timing stopped at: 76.42 73.41 151
```

Is there any package or workaround for this issue? In the end i'll be using the `reticulate` package to load a sparse `csr` matrix from `numpy` in order to take advantage of the quicker and memory efficient `text2vec` package for running glove, which requires the data to be in `dgCMatrix` format.

**Edit**

I've also tried `spam` with the following lines of code to simulate a large and sparse matrix.

```
library(spam)
test_matrix <- spam_random(nrow = 1900000, ncol = 1900000, density = 0.001)
```

It will run with the following warning:

```
Warning message in spam_random(nrow = 1900000, ncol = 1900000, density = 0.001):
"integer overflow in 'cumsum'; use 'cumsum(as.numeric(.))'"
```

Until it eventually times out with the following error message:

```
Error in if (rowp[i] == rowp[i + 1L]) next: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
Traceback:

1. system.time(test_matrix <- spam_random(nrow = 1900000, ncol = 1900000, 
 .     density = 0.001))
2. spam_random(nrow = 1900000, ncol = 1900000, density = 0.001)
Timing stopped at: 1657 228.3 1903
```

Comment: it's still too large for R.. you can check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54405435/sparse-matrix-support-for-long-vectors-over-231-elements, I don't know if the package still works

Comment: So is there no workaround that might work? I know R 3.x can handle much longer vectors than `2^31`. I've tried `spam` with no luck (see edit above).

Comment: @Olivier text2vec glove takes dgTMatrix as input. So it actually needs `i, j, x` triplets. You can try to build triplet matrix with `sp_matrix <- sparseMatrix(i = i, j = j, x = as.numeric(x), dims=list(DIMS, DIMS), giveCsparse = F, check = F)`. Not sure if it will work.

Comment: @DmitriySelivanov Unfortunately it failed silently. ```Error in validityMethod(as(object, superClass)) :
  long vectors not supported yet: ../../src/include/Rinlinedfuns.h:522
Calls: <Anonymous> ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted```
Can I assume R just can't handle sparse matrices of this size?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but it seems yes.

Comment: To be clear on `spam`, you need to use `spam64` if you want int64 indices for your matrix.